# Set NotifyOnTargetUpdated for existing binding

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I have a binding in xaml `<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textStyle}" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />`.

I am attempting to write an attached behavior that reacts to the bound `DisplayText` value changing. If I specify `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` in the xaml, I can react to the change within the behavior and everything is fine, but I'd rather not depend on binding the Text property in a specific way just to make the behavior work.

My thought was to change the NotifyOnTargetUpdated value on the existing TextBlock.TextProperty binding when the behavior is opted in. I am using the below code to do so, where `tb` is the TextBlock being opted in.

```
var textBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);
textBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, textBinding);
```

The behavior is opted in like so, in the style:
`<Setter Property="behaviors:Text.AutoSizeText" Value="True"/>`

Initially this didn't work because `textBinding` was null. I can get around this by binding the `Text` property in xaml before the behavior property, but this still leaves an external dependency that I don't like (xaml ordering). If I *do* go this route, I get the below exception, which seems to indicate that I can't accomplish this in this way, at all.

`InvalidOperationException: Binding cannot be changed after it has been used.`

So then, how can I go about automatically handling setting NotifyOnTargetUpdated for the `Text` binding when the behavior is opted in?

Comment: I've added the usage of the behavior, but I'm not sure what you mean about binding `DisplayText` - I am binding to it in the TextBlock xaml above.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a sensible way to do this... You can have a separate property which you bind to, e.g. `my:Stuff.Text="{Binding DisplayText}"` instead of binding to `Text`, which would let you default the binding to `NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true`

Comment: You're suggesting an internal `Text` property that binds to the same target as the `TextBlock.TextProperty` binding, created in code with the NotifyOnTargetUpdated value set correctly. I believe that could work, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it will have to forward to `TextProperty` under the hood, but it just exposes a binding with slightly different defaults. Which is still ugly and it's still just as easy to bind to the wrong property, but hey, it's an option

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but NotifyOnTargetUpdated turns on the notification about TextBlock.Text change, not DataContext.DisplayText.
Therefore, you are not watching DisplayText, but Text.
And if so, why don't you make gording easier: bind to the TextBlock.Text property.
Create an internal DependecyObject with one DependecyProperty and bind it to TextBlock.Text.

Comment: @EldHasp Correct. Ultimately `TextBlock.TargetUpdated` is raised when `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` on the binding and changes are made to DisplayText. What you are suggesting, I think, is basically what canton7 suggested. I prefer to bind internally to DisplayText because I'd prefer to bind to the source, if possible, rather than daisy-chain through the TextBlock.Text property.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem thanks to direction provided by @canton7. I was originally (as is often the case) looking for the way to implement my imagined solution, rather than a solution that fit my need. After adjusting my outlook, my working solution is thus:

Add the AttachedProperty `InternalText` to the behavior class, with a property changed handler.

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty InternalTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "InternalText", typeof(string), typeof(Text), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), HandleInternalTextChanged));
```

In the changed handler (`HandleInternalTextChanged` above) do the work that I would have done in a TargetUpdated handler if my original idea to set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` had worked out.

On opt-in to my behavior, create a binding from the opted-in `TextBlock.Text` to the `InternalText` attached property.

```
var internalBinding = new Binding { Source = tb, Path = new PropertyPath(TextBlock.TextProperty) };
tb.SetBinding(InternalTextProperty, internalBinding);
```

The `HandleInternalTextChanged` callback on `InternalTextProperty` allows me to work around being unable to change the `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` value by providing an alternate means of notifying on each change.

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer to bind internally to DisplayText because I'd prefer to bind to the source, if possible, rather than daisy-chain through the TextBlock.Text property.

If you need a binding to a source property, then it is created in a slightly different way.

```xml
    var binding =  BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(tb, TextBox.TextProperty);
    if (binding == null)
    {
        tb.ClearValue(InternalTextProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        tb.SetBinding(InternalTextProperty, binding);
    }
```